# How to add a marker on a point on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following dataframe using ggplot2 with an added column called Condition which has Yes or No values.

```
ID     Diagnosis Age_at_Diagnosis                  Condition
    0   A-1         Birth                0                No
    1   A-1   Lung cancer               25               Yes
    4   A-1         Death               50                No
    5   A-2         Birth                0                No
    6   A-2  Brain cancer               12                No
    8   A-2   Skin cancer               20                No
    11  A-2   Current age               23                No
    12  A-3         Birth                0                No
    13  A-3  Brain cancer               30                No
    15  A-3   Lung cancer               33               Yes
    17  A-3   Current age               35                No
```

I have successfully created the plots using the code below (ignore if there are few values, this is for the original data I am working on).

```
ggplot(new, aes(
    new$Age_at_Diagnosis,
    new$Individual_ID,
    color= new$Diagnosis,
    shape = new$Diagnosis,
    group=new$Individual_ID
  )) + 
  geom_line(linetype="solid", color="black", size=0.25) + 
  geom_point( size=2.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Diagnosis", values = c("red", "black", "dark blue","black", "maroon")) +   
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Diagnosis",values = c(16,8,124,15)) +
  ggtitle("Lung Cancer Diagnosis Only") + 
  xlab("Age at Diagnosis") + 
  ylab("Individual ID") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

I am trying to figure out how to add the condition column values into my plot. I want add a marker/circle on the point (diagnosis) if the Diagnosis has a "Yes" in the Condition column.

I have tried using `geom_point(data=new[new$Condition=='Yes',],pch=21,fill=NA,size=4)` but had no luck and ended up with either "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" or "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11): x, y, colour, group" errors.

I should point out that the Condition will be Yes only with Lung cancer diagnosis and no other cancers.

Comment: General tip: don't use `data$column` inside `aes()`. Just use column names. Using `$` will break more complicated graphs. `aes(x = Age_at_Diagnosis, y = Individual_ID, ...)` is good

Comment: Can you show the code you used to add `Condition` and/or give an example of the final dataset you are using to plot?  The column not being present may be causing the error.

Comment: @aosmith , i have the column but was too lazy to add it to my sample set. I've updated it. (sorry)

Comment: Your new line for the marker works for me with your example data (although the code didn't give quite enough colors or shapes so I commented out the `scale_*` lines).

Comment: I keep getting this error when I try it without the scale_* lines = Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11): x, y, colour, group

Comment: Oh, I know what happened.  You didn't take out the dollar signs as suggested above and I did. :)  Take those out and refer to bare column names; this is a good reminder (to me!) about how using dollar sign notation with ggplot2 can be really problematic.